# Handle google sign in provider errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I'm confused. i've been trying to wrap my head around this but still didn't find any solution. in my web app i have a sign up page. what i'd like to do is when the user sign up with his google account , check in my database if the email already exists. if it does then return 409 error. this is where i'm having trouble, i'd like if the response returned is 409 then display an error in my sign up component of "Email already exists". how do i achieve that ? here's my code. note that i'm using next 13.4 and next-auth 4

```
const handleGoogleSubmit = async (values, setSubmitting) => {
    const user = await signIn("google")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

return (
     <Button
             intent={"socialGoogle"}
              className={"w-full"}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleGoogleSubmit();
              }}
              icon={<GoogleBrandDefault />}
            >
              Continue with Google
     </Button>

)
```

my next auth api file

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        try {
          const req = await apiUserCheckEmail({ email: profile.email });
          return req;
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.status === 409) {
            return error;
          }
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
      // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
};
```

note that my backend is working fine. i've tested it with insomnia. the trouble is handling the error in my next auth file. please help me out !